# Shall we mark private methods as "static" as more as possible?

Tags: java, static, private

There are some private methods in a class, and they don't depend on any instance variables. They accept some arguments, and return a value, no side effects.

For example:

```
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public String getFullName() {
          return capWord(firstName) + " " + capWord(lastName);
    }
    private String capWord(String word) {
         return word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
    }
}
```

You see there is a `capWord` method in this class, which is `private` but not `static`. It's safe to mark it as `static`, but is there good enough reason to do this?

I have 2 reasons:

1. when I see a method is `static`, I know it won't read/write instance variables, which makes the code more readable
2. better performance

But I don't know if they are enough to convince other members in team to change their `private` methods to `static` as more as possible.

Comment: Why won't you use WordUtils.capitalize(str) or WordUtils.capitalizeFully(str)? http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: This method is just an example, not in my real code. But thank you for the tips :)

Comment: Actually Rebelek's comment, if generalized, is also one option to consider.  If your private method can safely be made static and does not reference any other static class members it may be adivisable to either move it to an utility class in your code-base or use an utility from a library such as mentioned by Rebelek.  This is especially true if such or similar code is used elsehwere.  This is in accordance to the DRY principle.

Comment: Also consider posting such questions on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.  Seems more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put forward two reasons for declaring such a method as `static`.

Your first reason is valid, more or less.  (It is actually saying more than what you said.  A `static` method can't explicitly or implicitly call instance methods either!  But it *could* have side-effects on objects that are passed as arguments, that are accessible via other static methods, and so on.).

Anyway ...

- It can improve readability if you declare a method as `static` to declare that it is not dependent on the state of a target object.  However, for a typical small private "helper" method like that, it is pretty obvious that the method doesn't depend on instance variables.
- The flip-side is that when you declare the method as `static`, you are *constrained* by that.  For a `private` method, that constraint is localized to the current class ... and easy to modify.  But for a non-private method, the constraint may affect other classes and cause problems.

Your second reason is debatable.  If the method in question is small, then it is likely to be inlined by the JIT compiler, and that will negate any potential performance benefit.  And even if there is a performance benefit, it is likely to be one or two instructions in the calling sequence, which is probably negligible compared to the application's overall performance.

In summary, I think the "case" for declaring private methods like that to be `static` is weak, and possibly incorrect.  It is not something you should pester your colleagues about ... IMO ... unless you can present *convincing* evidence that it actually does affect performance AND that the performance improvement is *significant to the overall application performance*.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really seem like a question, but more of an opinion.

As neutral as possible, Java is very Object-Oriented in its model. Having "utility" methods that would serve multiple instances defined as static is a very valid approach.

Non-static methods are more of an object-oriented approach, and it comes down to whether or not it makes sense to have an instance calling that method.

For example, I may have a `Launcher` class that offers several utility methods for influencing my program, but I may only want one `Thread` to be in control of those methods. So, I create an instance of that `Launcher` class to access its methods, and use a static method to retrieve a lock on the `Launcher`.

Ultimately, it is an organizational preference from one programmer to the next.

There is no significance performance gain from static vs non-static methods. If an instance of an object is already created, it won't make any difference, and creating an object vs not has no perceivable performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would mark it as static but it is not an extreme performance benefit, and is more organizational. If you work better with it static, make it static. If you are better with it being an instance method anyway, by all means do so. It's marked private, so you're free to do whatever you need/prefer to do to make it work.

While it is certainly acceptable to mark your private methods as static when appropriate, there is no need to try to persuade others to do this. Private methods are designed so others' private methods need not concern you here, as would be in your case.

There's no need to beg FooDev to make his method static, as he's the only one calling it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Making a method `static` signals to a human reader that the method is [*stateless*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_%28computer_science%29), which is an important aspect to know.

Unless a stateless method is *required* to be an instance method (ie non-static), for example because the class must fulfill an interface etc, it can be a good design choice to make stateless methods static.